# How test the action text? how to add the action text in yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

How to add body in action text?

**Post.rb**

```
has_rich_text :body
```

**test/fixtures/posts.yml**

```
one:
  name: <%= Faker::Name.unique.name %>
  body: "body"
```

posts_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @post = posts(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get posts_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I run the PostsControllerTest expected success response but got
`Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "posts" has no columns named "body"`.

**Using rails 6.0, Ruby 2.7.1**

Answer (score 12):

Create file:

**test/fixtures/action_text/rich_texts.yml**

if it does not exist, then add these lines to it:

```
post_one:
  record: one (Post)                          # record: record name (in_yml) in association (ModelName)
  name: body                                  # has_rich_text :name_of_rich_text_attribute
  body: <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>    # actual rich text content
```

You also should remove `body: "body"` from **test/fixtures/posts.yml**.

Comment: This setup is really unintuitive, so thank you for pointing me in the right direction, @MibraDev!

Comment: Thanks for elucidating the mystery for me! Hit my head against the wall for a few hours until I found your answer. I wish this would be documented in the guide: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html